# SQLite Update doesn't change statement in database

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to make a method which will make "transactions" in data base. It should take balance of account from db and withdraw an amount, then change balance state in db, but it's not doing anything.

```
public void balanceTransactionChange(Integer accountIdFrom, Integer accountIdTo, double amount){
        double balanceFrom = 0;
        double balanceTo = 0;


        if (Objects.equals(accountIdTo, accountIdFrom)){
            dbConnection coon = new dbConnection();
            String query = "select * from Account WHERE Account.id = "+accountIdFrom.toString();
            try {
                double balance = 0;
                Statement statement = coon.getConnection().createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    balance = resultSet.getDouble("balance");
                }

                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();

                String second = "UPDATE Account SET balance = ? WHERE Account.id = ?";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = coon.getConnection().prepareStatement(second);
                preparedStatement.setDouble(1, balance - amount);
                preparedStatement.setInt(2,accountIdFrom);

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                System.err.println("aaaaa");
                preparedStatement.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                coon.closeConnection();
            }
}
```

I tried to use Replace instead of update, but its just adding in table completely new state

Comment: What is `amount` and where and how is it set?

Comment: amout is amount of "money" wich goes from one acount's balance to another

Comment: a. what is its value? (Make sure it isn't zero) b. are you even sure that the `if` block is executing?

Comment: amount is defenetly not zero and if block defently executing

Comment: Can't see it at the mo but `String balanceUpdate = "UPDATE Account SET balance = balance - ? WHERE Account.id = ?";` (using `amount` as the first parameter) would eliminate the first query

Comment: sadly but it's didn't help either

Comment: Two other things to check: a. you're connected to the db you think you are b. you have update privileges

Comment: @Liron, Your code is broken, it causes either bank or client to loose money. You need to first read something about isolation levels, pessimistic/optimistic locks, etc.